# Do older versions of Android upgrade the chrome webview?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, webview

Does the webview component within Android get upgraded with system updates on on older versions of Android? Meaning, if I have a device that is running Android 4.4 Kitkat, and I have run all the system updates, will the webview in fact be at a much more recent version? The reason I ask is I am building a webapp that needs to run within a supported version of the webview component.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the WebView through Play Store is a feature new in Android 5.0 (and in Android 7.0 this component was folded into Chrome itself, eliminating the separate Android System WebView app). Older versions of Android have a version of WebView that can only be updated through a system update.

[According to developer.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview):

> The WebView shipped with **Android 4.4 (KitKat)** is based on the same code as Chrome for Android version 30. This WebView does not have full feature parity with Chrome for Android and is given the version number **30.0.0.0**.
>
> The updated WebView shipped with Android **4.4.3** has the version number **33.0.0.0**.

The Android 4.4 WebView is based on Chrome, while older versions were based on WebKit.

In https://caniuse.com they indicate which features you'll be able to use in "Android 4.4 browser".